# composer update without dependencies

Tags: php, yii2, composer-php, yii2-advanced-app

[image]I am using yii2 framework since last few weeks. But now I am getting some issues with composer itself.

Just for info, I am using ubuntu 14.04

When I require some new package / extensions, I do the composer add by using composer require command. But I noticed that sometimes it's removing few of the existing packages from my vendor and project.

I tried with following commands.

```
composer require dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset "*"

composer require 2amigos/yii2-file-upload-widget:~1.0
```

And also tried with some googling.

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/672/install-specific-yii2-vendor-extension-dependency-without-updating-other-packages/

But it's not working.

Is there a way to add a new package / extension into your existing yii 2 project without removing existing packages or without any composer update command?

**Composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "sganz/yii2-advanced-api-template",
    "description": "Improved Yii 2 Advanced Application Template By Sandy Ganz, Original by Nenad Zivkovic",
    "keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "advanced", "improved", "application template", "nenad", "sganz"],
    "type": "project",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "support": {
        "tutorial": "http://www.freetuts.org/tutorial/view?id=6",
        "source": "https://github.com/sganz/yii2-advanced-api-template.git"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable":true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
        "nenad/yii2-password-strength": "*",
        "mihaildev/yii2-ckeditor": "*",
        "dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-codeception": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "*",
        "codeception/specify": "*",
        "codeception/verify": "*"
    },
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "protected/vendor",
        "process-timeout": 1800
    },
    "extra": {
        "asset-installer-paths": {
            "npm-asset-library": "protected/vendor/npm",
            "bower-asset-library": "protected/vendor/bower"
        }
    }
}
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check if the packages which are removed are required in your `composer.json` (before you run `composer require`). It also can be that the removed packages are sub requirements of another package which was updated (`composer require` automatically runs a `composer update`) and are no longer needed by this package.

Comment: @Peh I've an existing big project developed long time ago, now when I am trying to add new packages, it's removing some of the existing packages.

Comment: OK, can you edit your question and show your `composer.json` and a list of the packages which are removed?

Comment: @Peh You can see the screen shot which shows which packages are removed.

Comment: And your `composer.json`?

Comment: Added, but I want to add new packages without any composer update, is that possible ?

Comment: I answered your question below.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
composer --no-update require dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset:*
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your problem is, that the packages which are removed are NOT in the `require` nor in `require-dev` section of your `composer.json`. So I assume that the removed packages formerly were (sub-)required by any of the other packages in your `composer.json` and with the newer version of these packages this requirement was dropped. This should be a normal behavior and should be no problem for your project!
2. As @Bizley already showed you can add a requirement without updating the old ones:

   ```
   composer --no-update require dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset:*
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem few days ago to install a package but when I installed the package all the project updated and my project became broken.So I replace my last vendor again,So I found a safe way for better and safer upgrading packages:

1. archiving your vendor to a zip or rar file and copy composer.json too.
2. add package to composer or install with composer require.
3. dont clear command line screen and copy its screen into a txt file to find versions
4. find your vital and main packages like yiisoft/yii2 and .... and copy their versions.
   for doing this open txt file and search in upgrade lines and find something like below:
   `- Upgrading yiisoft/yii2 (2.0.39.3 => 2.0.41.1): Extracting archive` means that your current version is 2.0.39.3,so copy this version on composer.json like below:*(without ~ and ^)*
   `"yiisoft/yii2": "2.0.39",`
5. remove project vendor folder and extract backup vendor and finally run
   `composer install` or `composer update`.

***note:*** dont remove vendor and composer.json backup till your project will works correctly then you can remove them.
**this is a manually way for upgrading vendors for don't upgrade in vital framework updates temporary like for my project update that yii released Yii2.0.41.*
**a very important note is from yii upgrade notes from [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.41/framework/UPGRADE.md) that:**

> Note: This document assumes you have composer installed globally so that you can run the composer command. If you have a composer.phar file inside of your project you need to replace composer with php composer.phar in the following.
>
> Tip: Upgrading dependencies of a complex software project always comes at the risk of breaking something, so make sure you have a backup (you should be doing this anyway ;) ).

so running `composer update` command directly could break part of your application like me that my admin pannel was broken.

good luck ;)

Answer (score -1):

To avoid uninstallation of other extensions just do following steps.

```
1) "dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset"  : "2.*" 
2) "2amigos/yii2-file-upload-widget": "~1.0"
```

to the require section of your composer.json file.

```
2) php composer.phar update
```

run this command in Cmd.